# Redirecting to a new path after user updates their profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

Having an interesting issue with redirects. On my user update page (at /username/edit), users can update their name, email and **username**. Once the update is complete, if the user updates their username, the path that they are redirected (in this case, its `edit_user_path` causes an error:

```
Cannot redirect to nil!
```

My Users controller looks like this:

```
def update
    find_user

    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        sign_in @user
        flash[:success] = "User updated"
        redirect_to edit_user_path
    else
        flash[:notice] = "There was an error updating this user:"
        redirect_to edit_user_path
    end
end
```

`find_user` is a method to find `@user`.

Essentially, how do I force the routes to update once this update happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps try:

```
edit_user_path(@user)
```

Answer (score 1):

The router needs the user id to know which user to edit..

```
redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)
```